# String type in WCF service interpreted as JAXBelement in JavaClient

Tags: java, wcf, jaxbelement

I have the following WCF web service:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SaveInwardDocument(InwardDocument document);
}

public class Serice:IService{
   void SaveInwardDocument(InwardDocument document){...};
}

[DataContract]
public class InwardDocument{
   [DataMember]
   public Citizen {get;set;}
   //some other enum properties
   [DataMember]
   public string Remarks {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Citizen{
   //Citizen proeperties
}
```

When I generate a proxy class in a java client based on the wsdl of the above service, I get JaxBelement for the type of `Citizen` and `Remarks` properties of the `InwardDocument` classes. That's not the case when I try to create proxy class of an asmx service. What do I have to do to get string as string and custom class as a complex type, not JaxBelement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging lots of resources, especially [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/DataBinding5.html)  and [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/apirefs.1112/e28159/oracle/iam/connectormgmt/jaxb/ObjectFactory.html) and realizing that I was not the only one facing this issue I found out that there is a class called ObjectFactory that is generated automatically with the help of which I can easily create certain JAXBElement instances to be passed as inputs to a WCF service function. This class has as many public instance methods that return JAXBElement objects as the number of JAXBElement generated from WSDL. Say you have a JAXBElement LastName input. To pass the actual data to this input all you have to do is this:

```
 ObjectFactory factory=new ObjectFactory();
 factory.createLastName("Gates");
```

This way, you shouldn't have any issues consuminga wcf service.