# Error when deserializing Java client request to WCF service

Tags: web-services, wcf, deserialization, java-client

I have a WCF service with yet only one method:

```
[OperationContract]
void SaveDocument (InwardDocument doc);

[DataContract]
public class InwardDocument{
   [DataMember]
   public Citizen Citizen {get;set;}
   ....
}

[DataContract]
public class Citizen{
   [DataMember]
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   ....
}
```

I've tested the service with both WCF test client and a separate .NET console application. In both cases the service works as expected. But when a java client tries to consume it, a deserialization problem occurs. I've put some markers inside the SaveDocument method to see what causes the problem:

```
public void SaveDocument(InwardDocument doc){
   if(doc==null)
      throw new ArgumentnullException("InwardDocument");
   if(doc.Citizen==null)
      throw new ArgumentnullException("InwardDocument.Citizen");//This exception is thrown when consumed by java client
}
```

As you can see the first exception is skipped which means `doc` argument itself is not null but for some reason, the Citizen property is null. The guy who generates the request in java client confirms that the InwardDocument.Citizen property is not null by debugging the code. In fact we've had a problem generating the proxy class in that java client which I describe in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011067/string-type-in-wcf-service-interpreted-as-jaxbelement-in-javaclient). So I'm assuming it has something to do with that same problem.Maybe I need to add some more attributes to my classes and their members to care of any such problems that might occur in other platforms? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by incorrect creation of the corresponding JAXBelement instances. The solution to the problem is in  [this SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32074498/751796)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add Know Type attribute in your InwardDocument class. See link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Citizen))]
public class InwardDocument{
   [DataMember]
   public Citizen Citizen {get;set;}
   ....
}
```

Comment: That did not help, unfortunately

Comment: Try to use fiddler to snippet the body of soap message before sending and after receive just to make that their has value.

Comment: I've just been able to succesfully receive request from java client. But I omitted all the JAXBelement inputs.